# How to bring focus to a text field when you hover over it

Tags: javascript

How do you bring focus to a text field when you hover the mouse on top of the field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

without jquery..

```
<input type=text   ....   onMouseOver="this.focus();">
```

Comment: Logic should be separate from structure and content, therefore using the traditional attribute way of binding events is not clean.

Comment: No offense, but all I heard was "blah blah blah."

Comment: actually whatever uses less code and still has no errors is always better Delan...

Answer (score 2):

```
myInputField.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    e.target.focus();
}, false);
```

Comment: just going to note this is correct for standards compliant browsers, but not IE.